# Different behavior of contentSize with iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, collectionview, contentsize

I have a strange behavior of contentSize property. I scroll a list of image in a collectionView until the contentOffset of my collectionView is equal to the contentSize of the collectionView minus the width of last image:

```
self.pictureCollectionView.contentOffset.x == self.pictureCollectionView.contentSize.width - widthOfLastImage
```

It's work for iPhone iOS 6.0 - 7.0 but not for iPad. This is the behavior:

iPad http://www.flickr.com/photos/110564188@N03/11205431886/
iPhone http://www.flickr.com/photos/110564188@N03/11205401415/

Someone can help me?

Here the code: github.com/mayoita/ContentSizeProblem

Comment: I think you have to remove Autoresizing in view.

Comment: Try logging the value of contentSize.width. Is it what you expect on iPad?

Comment: Hi Samir, I had set the autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingNone but nothing change.

Comment: Hi Jamie, the contentSize.width log is always the same for iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Here the project: https://github.com/mayoita/ContentSizeProblem